# DB Connection to Godaddy

Tags: database, godaddy-api, appery.io

I am using Appery.io platform and I've created an API on the GoDaddy and then get an error like  in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhZxl.jpg).

What is the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Such an error can indicate only one thing - some of the credentials are not correct or valid. It looks like the Host might not be defined correctly.

Please check this sample section to review what it looks like for HostBuddy: https://docs.appery.io/docs/apiexpress-quickstart-creating-apis-for-relational-database-ionic-5#creating-database-connection
To learn where to look for the needed credentials, please check the documentation of the hosting service.